# Mail.app rules are very slow

Tags: mail.app, mojave

After I updated my Mac to Mojave, the mail app became very slow, particularly with the rules.

I have rebuilt mailbox, restarted Mac and Mail multiple times.

My account connects to MS Exchange.

It takes ages to open rules, scroll down and add new senders to a rule I have created to mark "spam" and move all emails from this sender to junk folder. I have checked today, and to run the rule on one email takes about 1 minute. Any ideas?

Comment: I had no end of problems with Macs and iOS devices using Mail.app to connect to Exchange servers. Finally, out of desperation, I started using and recommending Outlook. The problems went away. YMMV and you may not *like* Outlook (I sure don't) but you will have all sorts of problems with Apple Mail connecting to Exchange. I have no idea why but for most people Outlook works better. Also a long list of senders to mark as spam is a recipe to slow down **any** email app.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are blocking Spam recipients is not recommended. Adding  lots of single rules will slow down your Email client. Instead, enable the [built-in Junk filter feature](https://support.apple.com/guide/mail/reduce-junk-mail-mlhlp1065/12.0/mac/10.14) or use a Third-Party tool e.g. [SpamSieve](https://c-command.com/spamsieve/)

Answer (score -1):

I've had the same issue for Mojave and now Catalina. I've posted several 'suggestions' to Apple for improvements, especially the clunky UI, but nothing's come through yet!

The only way I know to speed things up is to move to a new, identical rule once the number of conditions grows to over 100, otherwise the interface just gums up.